# Converting string of an array back to array

Tags: java

I have this string : `"[  name = preload cacheHits = 0 onDiskHits = 0 inMemoryHits = 0 misses = 0 size = 0 averageGetTime = 0.0 evictionCount = 0 ]",`

and want to convert it in array like `[  name = preload cacheHits = 0 onDiskHits = 0 inMemoryHits = 0 misses = 0 size = 0 averageGetTime = 0.0 evictionCount = 0 ],`

How can we do it?

Comment: ehm ... I don't see a valid array type there. a composite object, sure, but not an array, since they're different types.

Comment: It's not array. maybe a MAP is right for you? I see it's more suitable for an associative array

Comment: @skr have you debug and checked whether it's coming as array or string. if you will debug at response then for array you will get `response=ArrayList<E>` and for string it will give you `response="[  name = preload cacheHits = 0 onDiskHits = 0 inMemoryHits = 0 misses = 0 size = 0 averageGetTime = 0.0 evictionCount = 0 ]"`

Comment: @TanmayNaik, I get the data in string form, I can not do much at the backend as well as the library that sends this info is sending it in string form. I have managed to convert it in Json using javascript. I was looking for a solution in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
String response="[ name = preload cacheHits = 0 onDiskHits = 0 inMemoryHits = 0 misses = 0 size = 0 averageGetTime = 0.0 evictionCount = 0 ]";
String replace = response.replaceAll("^\\[|]$","");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(replace));
```

Comment: I never thought I could easily do it using regex.